# WCF service void method Will operation complete with Windows Impersonation

Tags: wcf, impersonation

I have a WCF which is configured on Windows Authentication. This means that only authenticated Windows users will be able to access. I have a method which does not return anything but spins up a thread that does some long running task under the called windows user impersonation.

My code is below:

```
public void SampleTask();
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(this.Activity);
}

private void Activity()
{
    WindowsIdentity identity = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity;
    using (WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = identity.Impersonate())
        {
        // Log status in a log database as "In Progress"
            // Do long running task (accessing database as current user)
        // retreive the results and save in a file
        // Update the log database as "Complete"
        }
}
```

My question is will the task still complete of retrieving the results and saving it and put the status as it should. Or will the impersonation will not work as there will be no open session. Or am I mistaken

Regards,
Girija Shankar

Comment: The session should remain open (assuming the connection isn't dropped or something else goes wrong) as long as the method is running.  Just because it returns `void` doesn't mean it's a fire-and-forget type operation.  Perhaps you're confusing operations that return `void` with operations that are marked as `IsOneWay=true`?  In either event, I'd expect the impersonation to continue regardless as it's set at the beginning of the method.

Comment: @Tim : thanks for the reply. So in this case can I use IsOneWay=true as well instead of what I have currently ? Will that work on WCF rest endpoint ? I am more worried on the Impersonation context. Will it continue or will it just throw error (What I was thinking was that since the channel is closed the Identity will be invalid). Also what do you mean when you say connection dropped ? What will happen if Client application is closed. Will it still work and complete?

Comment: Once the method is called, it will run to end (unless an error is encountered), regardless of what happens on the client side.   Once you establish the impersonation context, whether the client stays connected or not the impersonation context should remain in effect.  The whole idea behind web services (be it SOAP or REST) is that the client and the service are **not** tightly-coupled, and with the exception of the service methods are completely independent.  Once the client requests the method to start, it has no further interest in what happens.

Comment: So in this case, I would definitely recommend using `IsOneWay = true` to prevent the client from being tied up waiting for a response (even though it's a void method, the service will send back a response).  In short, 1) use `IsOneWay  = true` and 2) the impersonation context is established and maintained in the scope of the service's method, so whatever happens to the client should have no bearing on the service.

Comment: How do I mark the comments as answer? I do not get the option :(

Comment: You can't accept comments.  I can post the above information as an answer if it worked for you later today.

Comment: Please do that. It works for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session should remain open as long as the method is executing.  Even if the method is returning `void`, the request that started the execution of the method will be replied to.

If you don't need a reply from the service, you can use the `IsOneWay = true` attribute on the method, which will tell the service to not send a reply to the client.  Since this is a long-running method that is not returning data to the client, that makes it a good candidate for being a one-way method.  In this case I'm not sure if the session would remain open or not, but it doesn't matter because the impersonation context will be scoped to the service, and have no dependency on the client.

In your method, you can see this because of the declaration:

```
WindowsIdentity identity = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity;
```

The variable `identity` is scoped to the `Activity` method.

```
using (WindowsImpersonationContect ctx = identity.Impersonate())
```

The variable `ctx` is likewise scoped to the `using` block within the `Activity` method.

The only time you would run into a problem that I can think of is if the service throws an exception and crashes - then of course the method wouldn't finish.

To sum up, since the impersonation is based on the identity the service is running under, and you're not returning any data to the client, session should have no impact on both the method running to completion or the identity the service is running under.